# File Framework for Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, files

[File Framework](http://drupal.org/project/fileframework) is a collection of modules which allow uploading, converting and displaying different media type files as Drupal nodes.

> Metadata is extracted from uploaded files using EXIF, getID3, pdfinfo
>   and stored as Resource Description Framework (RDF).
>
> A node of type file is created for each uploaded file. This gives a
>   revision control and will integrate with views.
>
> Each file is converted to number of other MIME formats using available
>   open source converters. For example a MS Word file can be
>   automatically converted to PDF, OpenDocument Text (using OpenOffice
>   daemon / LibreOffice + JODConverter), Plain text (using catdoc), Flash
>   video (using SWFTools), JPEG (using GhostScript) and Zip (using gzip).
>   Converted (derived) files are saved in the Bitcache and their metadata
>   is extracted and saved in the RDF along with the relation to the
>   original file. All derived files are listed and can be downloaded.

Unfortunatelly the module is available for Drupal 6 only.

Is there any similar solution available for Drupal 7 ?

Please follow http://drupal.org/node/1827110 if you are interested in File Framework port for Drupal 7.

Comment: related to http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/3754/2916

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media) as your starting point, and improving it if needed. That's the D7 solution aiming to solve similar problems to the File Framework (and other D6 modules).